# Option or Command key as Meta key for LispBox on Macintosh

Tags: emacs, lisp

I'm new to emacs and have just downloaded LispBox (from the Practical Common Lisp page) with SBCL to my Macintosh.  I do know enough to realize I want either the option or Command key to be the meta key.

The emacs version delivered with LispBox doesn't pay attention to .emacs in my home directory.

Emacs as delivered with LispBox fires up into a REPL. I can't figure out what I should type to set up a command key as Meta, nor where or how to configure it permanently.

Edit:  I'm not really interested in loading up another version of emacs. I already have emacs running from the Terminal with my option key mapped as meta. Being able to closely follow the "Practical Common Lisp" tutorial, which assumes LispInABox, is what I'm interested in here.

TIA.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Navigate to `/Applications/Lispbox/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS` and edit `lispbox.`sh, removing the `--no-init-file` parameter.  Then, inside `~/.emacs`, add `(setq mac-command-modifier 'meta)`

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative check out [Ready Lisp](http://www.newartisans.com/projects/ready-lisp.html) for Mac OS X. It uses Aquamacs for Emacs.

Aquamacs is a specially for Mac OS X enhanced GNU Emacs.

If you run Emacs in a Mac OS X terminal, you can set the Option key to be the Meta key using the 'Preferences' dialog.

Comment: @Rainer: I read that in mac you do not need to set Option key to be Meta key. Mac considers automatically Option as Meta in Emacs. The shortcoming of having Meta instead of Option is the incompatibility of Meta with other Mac's terminal apps. My Emacs runs beautifully only with the "Option" key.